Host a static JS-enabled webpage behind SharePoint credentials
Looking for a simple solution. My clients want a static JS-enabled webpage deployed in such a way that users need to enter their SharePoint credentials in order to see it. As a result, we cannot put it on a public server, but we can also not put it on an internal server since that would require VPN.
A slightly different question has been asked before, but the answer appears obsolete.
Ideally, the link would read https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/..../site.html and the page would get served up like a true html page.

You could create a wiki page with a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP). Then you can host your html, js, css, etc. files in the SiteAssets library. Your cewp simply points to the location of the html file and you have it do anything you want.
I have deployed single page apps this way since earlier versions of SharePoint and it still works today.
You can easily access SharePoint lists using pnpjs if you wish, as you will be authenticated.
There are some features and settings that need to be enabled, but once done, it works great.
